# Does Inkscape work properly with large files on Mac OS?

Tags: compatibility

I am not a Mac user yet, but I am used to working with Inkscape on Linux platforms. I use Inkscape to create website mockups and sometimes the files are big and require a lot of RAM.

I would like to know if someone has some experience working with Inkscape in Mac OS?

I am planning to buy a MacBook but I can't live without Inkscape.

Comment: Are you aware that linux runs very well in virtualization in case you don't like how it works on the Mac OS?

Comment: Now I have 4 mounths working with inkscape and Mac OS , and everything is ok

Comment: Please feel free to add an answer below - it's perfectly fine to have an honest question and the answer by the same person. It helps the site and as long as you keep the question simple and add all the commentary to the answer, you're likely to get up votes for both.

Answer (score 1):

Now that I have a Mac to test this with, working with Inkscape it seems to be ok. (I am a web designer and my files are usually several layouts inside the same workspace.)

I have been working on my MacBook Pro for 4 months now without any problems related to Inkscape.